# How to ensure that Python type checking tools correctly recognize "type-conversion decorators"?

Tags: python, type-conversion, python-decorators, python-typing, typechecking

Basically I am looking for a way to implement a Python decorator, which tries to automatically convert "suitable" argument to another type (from "str" to "Palindrome" in the example below). From the outside the function should look like it can be called with a "suitable" type, whereas on the inside the function does not have to deal with the type conversion logic and is ensured that the value was correctly converted previously (or an exception was raised). I am looking for a generic solution which correctly typechecks, e.g., in VSCode. I composed an example below & am very happy to hear you inputs.

````
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, Self, TypeVar

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")


class Palindrome(str):
    def __new__(cls, value: str) -> Self:
        if value == value[::-1]:
            return super().__new__(cls, value)
        raise ValueError(f"{value!r} is not a palindrome.")

    def is_even(self) -> bool:
        return len(self) % 2 == 0


def magic(func: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, R]:
    def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        new_args = []
        for arg, arg_type in zip(args, func.__annotations__.values()):
            if arg_type == Palindrome:
                arg = Palindrome(arg)
            new_args.append(arg)

        return func(*new_args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
        # ^^^ would be nice to have if this would also typecheck

    return wrapper


def working_no_so_magic(func: Callable[[Palindrome, str], None]) -> Callable[[str, str], None]:
    def wrapper(palindrome: str, text: str) -> None:
        return func(Palindrome(palindrome), text)
    return wrapper


@magic
def do_something(palindrome: Palindrome, text: str) -> None:
    print(type(palindrome), palindrome, palindrome.is_even())
    print(type(text), text)


do_something(Palindrome("aibohphobia"), "aibohphobia")
# Expected & actual output:
# >> <class '__main__.Palindrome'> aibohphobia False
# >> <class 'str'> aibohphobia

do_something("aibohphobia", "aibohphobia")
# ^^^ The above line should correctly typecheck!
#
# Expected & actual output (with the @magic decorator):
# >> <class '__main__.Palindrome'> aibohphobia False
# >> <class 'str'> aibohphobia
# Actual output (without the @magic decorator applied):
# >> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_even'

do_something(Palindrome("not-a-palindrome"), "aibohphobia")
# Typechecks correctly, and correctly raises an ValueError.


do_something("not-a-palindrome", "aibohphobia")
# Should typecheck correctly (although it would be amazing if we could catch that in the type system), 
# but does not using the current @magic implementation.
# Correctly raise an ValueError at runtime.
```python
````

Comment: I don't get it. Are you looking for help with type annotations or with the implementation? Because you said both. Also I am pretty sure this is not a _minimal_ example of the problem, it is all over the place. Can you please focus your question on **one** thing and explain precisely what your goal is and what is not working right now?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond! I am sorry for being unclear. I am looking for help on how to implement "@magic" in (1) a generic way and (2) in a way which ensures that "do_something" typechecks correctly. My code shows how to get (1) and (2) individually, but not how to get both (1) and (2) at the same time.